# ui-router Abstract State Combination

Tags: angular-ui-router

I created two json files where I'm getting the data through a controller homeCtrl and articleCtrl. Than I have a state to display all my data places and articles

```
.state('overview', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/overview',
    templateUrl: '_/partial/overview/overview.html',
    controller: 'homeCtrl',
    resolve: {
        places: ['$http', function($http) {
             return $http.get('_/api/place.json').then(function(response) {
                 return response.data;
             })
         }] 
    }
})

.state('overview.all', {
    url: '/all',
    templateUrl: '_/partial/overview/overview-all.html',
    controller: 'homeCtrl',
    resolve: {
        places: ['$http', function($http) {
             return $http.get('_/api/place.json').then(function(response) {
                 return response.data;
             })
         }] 
    }
})

    .state('overview.articles', {
        url: '/articles',
        templateUrl: '_/partial/overview/overview-articles.html',
        controller: 'articleCtrl',
        resolve: {
            articles: ['$http', function($http) {
                 return $http.get('_/api/article.json').then(function(response) {
                     return response.data;
                 })
             }] 
        }
    })
```

Afterwards I created two states to get the data by id

```
.state('overview.detail-place', {
    url: '/:id/place',
    templateUrl: '_/partial/details/detail-place.html',
    controller: function($scope, $stateParams){
        $scope.place = $scope.places[$stateParams.id];
    }
})

.state('overview.detail-article', {
    url: '/:id/article',
    templateUrl: '_/partial/details/detail-article.html',
    controller: function($scope, $stateParams){
        $scope.article = $scope.articles[$stateParams.id];
    }
})
```

I have no problem going to the detail page of a place but when I want to go to an article I get this error, 99 being the id of the article.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '99' of undefined
    at new $stateProvider.state.state.state.state.state.state.state.state.controller (http://localhost:8888/%203.0v/_/js/app.js:86:53)
    at d (http://localhost:8888/%203.0v/_/lib/angular.min.js:34:265)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:8888/%203.0v/_/lib/angular.min.js:34:394)
    at http://localhost:8888/%203.0v/_/lib/angular.min.js:66:112
    at http://localhost:8888/%203.0v/_/lib/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:15323
    at J (http://localhost:8888/%203.0v/_/lib/angular.min.js:53:345)
    at f (http://localhost:8888/%203.0v/_/lib/angular.min.js:46:399)
    at http://localhost:8888/%203.0v/_/lib/angular.min.js:46:67
    at j (http://localhost:8888/%203.0v/_/lib/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:14566)
    at http://localhost:8888/%203.0v/_/lib/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:14835 <div class="main-container overview ng-scope" ui-view="">
```

Comment: Do you resolve the *articles* as well? as you do with *places*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is, that state `'overview.articles'` does initiate the **`articles`** collection

```
.state('overview.articles', {
    ...
    controller: 'articleCtrl',
    resolve: {
        articles: ....
```

So most- likely the 'articleCtrl' does place the articles into the $scope.articles.

BUT, this state: `'overview.detail-article'` in fact does not have access to that collection:

```
.state('overview.detail-article', {
    ...
    controller: function($scope, $stateParams){
        $scope.article = $scope.articles[$stateParams.id];
    }
```

And why? **because the `'overview.detail-article'` is not child state of the `'overview.articles'`**

But this still does not have to be enough with `ui-router`, check this:

- [Scope Inheritance by View Hierarchy Only](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#scope-inheritance-by-view-hierarchy-only) *(small cite:)*

> Keep in mind that scope properties only inherit down the state chain if the views of your states are nested. Inheritance of scope properties has nothing to do with the nesting of your states and everything to do with the nesting of your views (templates).
>
> It is entirely possible that you have nested states whose templates populate ui-views at various non-nested locations within your site. In this scenario you cannot expect to access the scope variables of parent state views within the views of children states.

So we need the detail state to be a child of articles *and also nested in the parent view*:

```
.state('overview.articles.detail-article', { ...
```

A plunker with [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/s3FloEdEDs6O0eIMPN7g?p=preview)...

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna look into the solution and come back later.

Comment: That is still possible! just try to read more about ui-rourter view [nesting](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views) and [multiple named view](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views). How? look, we can introduce some abstract state e.g. `overview.parent` this will have the resolve... and keep reference to articles. its children will be 1) list and 2) detail - both inheriting from parent scope the **articles** - and will be injected into same parent target ui-view! ;) ;) it is not so difficult... just try and play and come back...

Comment: I just tried to make a work around so the child will replace the parent view but yes, I'm gonna play with the nesting view and multiple named view and come back. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Definitely, once you'll get lost or ... come here and ask.. good luck with ui-router, amazing library ;)

Comment: I tried most of the solutions that I could come up with or find on the internet. I changed the name from `places` to `articles` and still nothing happens. I get the same error, it just doesn't want to read `{{article.name}}` or anything of that matter. This is the ui-router example on which I have everything based on right now http://plnkr.co/edit/gmtcE2?p=preview

Comment: Would you mind to formulate new question? maybe with a link to this. I will meanwhile try to put together an example, based on the above stuff... and later come to you. Maybe, meanwhile, you will get even better answer there... does it make sense?

Comment: I'm gonna do it in a couple of hours.

Comment: That will give me enough time. I promise: I will have an example for you then... *let me know about your new question*

Comment: Before I reformulate or you creating an example I have to mention that I can go to an article now I just can't get the `{{template}}`. I get this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : VM32154 angular.min.js.map:2`.

Comment: Look, to support what I told you above, there is a plunker which should show that all: http://plnkr.co/edit/s3FloEdEDs6O0eIMPN7g?p=preview if you still need some hlep, issue new quesiton and if none answer you, let me know... if I can help I will

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm gonna try to reconstruct my `app.js` file and the controllers. After seeing your example I am confident that I can manage to make it work.

Comment: Awesome! great to see that.. you must love ui-router... good luck

Comment: Just to give you an update. There was nothing wrong with my original code. For some reason it didn't want to take the content by `id` from the `articles json file` if the first object doesn't have an `id` of `0`. The credit goes to you because I saw in your example that the first place object has an `id` of `0` and the article object had the same thing.